# Add Parameter When Call Function Interface

Tags: c#

I have interface mamal have function walk

```
Interface Mamal{
    void walk();
}
```

And I implements interface mamal in class dog

```
class dog:Mamal{
    void walk(){}
}
```

How can I add parameter in function walk so the function should be

```
class dog:Mamal{
    void walk(int distance){}
}
```

Comment: is it only the dog class that needs to walk a distance or all mammals?

Comment: Interface Mamal { void walk(int distance); } ?

Comment: In the future, it will help if you post code that actually *compiles*. Makes it easier to get an answer with code as well.

Comment: @holmesfans: If only the `dog` class needs that method then what exactly is the problem?  You can add that method to that class and the `Mamal` type would never know or care about it.

Comment: I am sorry i mean the dog have distance in function walk but the other mamal don't have distance in function mamal

Comment: @holmesfans: Then the `dog` class has its own implementation.  It would have two `walk` methods, one without the parameter and one with the parameter.  That would work just fine.  Simply add the `walk()` interface method to your current `dog` class so it can have both.

Comment: But in my case I just have 2 class dog and cat and my professor told me to use function walk from Interface

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The interface is strict. You cannot change it. You can implement a *second* method in your dog class that has this parameter, but it won't be *the* method defined in the interface.

If you need that parameter in all methods, you can change the interface though.

Comment: The op could always make `walk()` call `walk(1)` if needed, it depends whether only dogs have a distance to walk

Comment: Sure, there are a ton of workarounds. I like the one above with the default value that defaults to an empty distance. But I guess that's way over the current level of the question right now.

Answer (score 2):

By changing the interface.  Or by not invoking the method from the interface.

For example, the code you have now should work fine but the parameter overload for `walk` can only be invoked on a `dog` object, not on a `Mamal` object.

Alternatively, you can change the interface:

```
Interface Mamal{
    void walk(int distance);
}
```

or:

```
Interface Mamal{
    void walk();
    void walk(int distance);
}
```

This would allow the overload to be called on the `Mamal` type as well.  Or, potentially, you can use an optional parameter.  Maybe something like this:

```
Interface Mamal{
    void walk(int? distance = null);
}
```

This should allow both overloads to be used and the single implementing method would check the incoming value.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface describes the public methods implementing classes should use - including their parameters. So, if you want an inheriting class to have a publicly accessible method with 1 (or 2, or 3 ... n) parameters, they should also be defined in that interface.

```
Interface Mamal{
    void walk(int distance);
}
class dog:Mamal{
    void walk(int distance){}
}
```